# BLACS context value and multiple MPI communicators

Tags: linear-algebra, parallel-computing, mpi, intel-mkl, scalapack

I am reposting here a question previously asked in stackoverflow: as suggested in a reply to my question, scicomp could be a better place to obtain some useful comments/suggestions for my problem.

I am trying to make some tests with BLACS/Scalapack (C interface, Intel MKL version) making use multiple MPI communicators: particularly, what I am trying to obtain is a set of BLACS contexts/grids corresponding (one-to-one) to a set of (disjoint) MPI communicators. While I have no problems in working with a single "global" communicator (`MPI_COMM_WORLD`) I have some difficulties with the multiple communicator case. I hope that you could give me some suggestions for the following problem.

I am a bit confused about the BLACS context variable value update after a call to `Cblacs_gridinit`: let's suppose to start with a "global" context corresponding to the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` communicator. I can obtain the corresponding BLACS context with the call:

```
MPI_Comm globalCommunicator(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MKL_INT globalContext(Csys2blacs_handle(globalCommunicator));
```

and create a grid on it with

```
Cblacs_gridinit(&globalContext,
                &c_blacsGridOrdering,
                MKL_INT i_nTaskRow,
                MKL_INT i_nTaskCol);
```

with, for example, `char c_blacsGridOrdering('R')`.

The globalContext value in this case is 0.

At some point in my code, which is making use of 6 MPI tasks,
an MPI communicator (`localCommunicator`) corresponding to the group of 4 tasks with id `[0;3]` is being created: at this point I would like to create a new BLACS context (`localContext`) for this "local" communicator and a local grid on it. I can do that with the code

```
MKL_INT localContext(Csys2blacs_handle(localCommunicator));

Cblacs_gridinit(&localContext,
                &c_blacsGridOrdering,
                MKL_INT i_nTaskRowLocal,
                MKL_INT i_nTaskColLocal);
```

where the above function call sequence is performed only by the tasks included in the local communicator.

The `localContext` value, after the call to `Csys2blacs_handle`, is equal to 1 (for each task of the local communicator) but it is modified and set to 0 by the subsequent call to `Cblacs_gridinit`.

Obviously this causes some problems in the rest of my code since, for example, if I try to retrieve the MPI communicator corresponding to `localContext` with a call to `Cblacs2sys_handle` I get a six task communicator corresponding to the initial `globalCommunicator`.

Most likely I am making some very stupid error (missing call to some BLACS functions??) or it is not clear to me the interplay between multiple MPI communicators and BLACS context/grids but I can not find what is wrong with my code.

Do you have some suggestions concerning the above problem? Many thanks for your help!

/////////
UPDATE 1
/////////

I have an update for my question which could be useful to find a solution or at least an explanation for the observed problem: the described problem is no more present if I initialize the first grid (the one making use of the global context) on a task grid whose size is such that all available MPI tasks are included, for example with MKL_INT i_nTaskRow(1) and MKL_INT i_nTaskCol(MPI_COMM_WORLD size). Is this behavior expected from BLACS? Many thanks again for your support!

Comment: I gave an answer on the stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488233)